# Getting a JOIN tables column in MySqlDataReader

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

I was wondering how I could select a query from a table when using JOIN? I want to select the column `expires_at` from table `user_auth_tickets` but how would I add that into this query, and would I even access it? Seeing as I can't just use `dUserInfo.GetDateTime("expires_at")` because what if both tables had a column called expires_at?

```
dbConnection.SetQuery("SELECT users.id,users.username,users.rank,users.motto,users.look,users.gender,users.last_online,users.credits,users.activity_points,users.home_room,users.block_newfriends,users.hide_online,users.hide_inroom,users.vip,users.account_created,users.vip_points,users.machine_id,users.volume,users.chat_preference,users.focus_preference,users.pets_muted,users.bots_muted,users.advertising_report_blocked,users.last_change,users.gotw_points,users.ignore_invites,users.time_muted,users.allow_gifts,users.friend_bar_state,users.disable_forced_effects,users.allow_mimic,users.rank_vip " +
    "FROM users " +
    "JOIN user_auth_tickets " +
    "ON users.id = user_auth_tickets.user_id " +
    "WHERE user_auth_tickets.auth_ticket = @sso AND ip_last = @lastIp " +
    "LIMIT 1"
);

dbConnection.AppendParameter("sso", sessionTicket);
dbConnection.AppendParameter("lastIp", ipAddress);

using (var reader = dbConnection.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (!reader.HasRows)
    {
        errorCode = 1;
        return null;
    }

    dUserInfo = reader;
}
```

Comment: You just need to have `user_auth_tickets.expires_at` in select statement.

Comment: Would you be willing to post an answer with more information? This doesn't explain how to fetch it from the reader, nor does it specify how exactly to add it in the select statement, using a prefix or not.

Comment: The comment says exactly what needs to be added in the select statement. And it can br fetched from datareader using the same approach which you use to fetch orther fields from the datareader. Did you try that? If not , please give it a try and let me know here if you face any issue in that.